# Ввод данных на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла проблема с вводом данных, до этого не работал на сайте и при вводе мне не понятно как это делать.

Вместо стандартного `int(input())` я встретил ввод `map(int, input().split())`.

Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Что именно непонятно? input() возвращает строку, split() делит строку по пробелам и выдаёт список, map вызывает указанную функцию для каждого элемента указанного списка и возвращает новый список (точнее итератор). Про всё это вы легко можете прочитать в любой документации и в любом учебнике по Python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map(int, input().split())` можно использовать в случае, если вводится несколько чисел через разделитель (в данном случае через пробел)

По шагам:

- `input()` возвращает строку (например: `"1 2 3"`)
- `split()` преобразует строку в `list` по разделителю - по умолчанию это пробел (результат: `["1", "2" ,"3"]`)
- `map` преобразует список в соответствие с функцией - в данном случае `int(elem)` (результат: `[1, 2 , 3]`

В результате выполнения кода получится объект `map`, который хорошо бы еще было обернуть в `list` (`list(map(....))`

Comment: Можно еще добавить что `list(map(int, input().split()))` тоже самое что `[int(i) for i in input().split()]`. А еще, `split` без параметров делит не просто по пробелам, а по их множеству: `'1   2 3'.split()` -> `['1', '2', '3']`, а вот строго по пробелу: `'1   2 3'.split(" ")` -> `['1', '', '', '2', '3']`. И еще, просто map удобно использовать если известно количество элементов, например если их 3: `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())`, но при желании можно обработать и сколько угодно: `a, *b = map(int, input().split())` -- первое числор попадет в `a`, а все остальные как список в `b`

Comment: Спасибо, большое